# Correct way of testing "associations" with Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations

I am trying to test the following scenario:

-> I have a model called Team which it just makes sense when it has been created by a User. Therefore, each Team instance has to be related to a User.

In order to test that, I have done the following:

```
describe Team do

...

  it "should be associated with a user" do
    no_user_team = Team.new(:user => nil)
    no_user_team.should_not be_valid
  end

...

end
```

Which forces me to change the Team model as:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :user

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :user

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Does this seem correct to you? I am just worried of make the :user attribute as accessible (mass assignment).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I usually use this approach:

```
describe User do
  it "should have many teams" do
    t = User.reflect_on_association(:teams)
    expect(t.macro).to eq(:has_many)
  end
end
```

A better solution would be to use the gem [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) which will allow you to simply:

```
describe Team do
  it { should belong_to(:user) }
end
```

Comment: What does shoulda actually tests? I want to ensure that when a new Team is created it actually belongs to a user.

Comment: `Shoulda` will test that, it will "ensure that the belongs_to relationship exists" (http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/Shoulda/Matchers/ActiveRecord#belong_to-instance_method). Thus, you can safely assume that when you create a new Team it will belong to a user.

Comment: I just tested that and I am able to do create a Team without specifying a User. Shoulda seems to just check if belongs_to exist in the model. I want to be sure that a Team has a User associated with it...I believe I need to validate that there is a presence of the associated User when creating a Team...

Comment: Hommer, I've done some research and it seems that you must add `validates :user, presence: true`in order to ensure that the foreign keys is properly set up. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176510/validates-associated-not-checking-existence-of-associations

Comment: New syntax for anyone these days is `expect(t.macro).to eq(:has_many)`.

Answer (score 27):

```
  it { Idea.reflect_on_association(:person).macro.should  eq(:belongs_to) }
  it { Idea.reflect_on_association(:company).macro.should eq(:belongs_to) }
  it { Idea.reflect_on_association(:votes).macro.should   eq(:has_many) }
```

Comment: i prefer this solution over the one above it. the shoulda gem broke all my pundit tests, and while there are workarounds, i'd rather just avoid using what appears to be a buggy gem.

Comment: This works with Rails 5.0.1, rspec 3.5.0, and rspec-rails 3.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MicroProxy < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :servers
end

describe MicroProxy, type: :model do
    it { expect(described_class.reflect_on_association(:servers).macro).to eq(:has_many) }
end
```

Comment: Duplicate of urbanczykd's answer

Comment: @Vasilisa the community convention for current Rspec version encourages the use of `expect` instead of `should`  http://www.betterspecs.org/#expect
Also when testing the same class `described_class` method is available for the maintaniabilty purpose of not locking the test with the class name 
https://blog.eq8.eu/article/expresive-tests-rspec.html#describing-intention

Comment: I agree, but you said nothing about it in the answer. Please, move your explanation from the comment to the answer

Answer (score 1):

RSpec is a ruby test framework, and not a rails framework.
belongs_to is a rails construct, and not a ruby construct.
Gems like [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) connect ruby and rails things and help you write good tests.

Having the above in mind and following official documentation, should help you stay up to date and understand what you are writing.

So, below is what I would write.

User model:

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  context 'associations' do
    it { should have_many(:teams).class_name('Team') }
  end
end
```

Team model:

```
RSpec.describe Team, type: :model do
  context 'associations' do
    it { should belong_to(:user).class_name('User') }
  end
end
```