# Testing ActiveRecord models relationships using NullDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

How I can test ActiveRecord model relationship let's say:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bucket
end
```

I would like to use `Rspec` + `NullDB` to test `bucket` association, so I need to test it without touching db.

Comment: What do you want to test about it? That it exists? Certain behavior? All the behavior?

Comment: That exists such method which is able to return correlated Bucket object.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: 
[Correct way of testing "associations" with Rspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723856/correct-way-of-testing-associations-with-rspec)

I believe [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) gem will help you.

You will be able to write something like that using it.

```
describe Order do
  it { should belong_to(:bucket) }
end
```