# Validation fails - cannot be blank - even though it is not blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

I have a model

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :CardColour
  validates :CardColour, presence:true
```

In the console I type

```
@a = Card.new(:card_colour_id =1)
```

However it is not valid. I ask why, by doing @a.errors, and the console tells me

```
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000000052e57e8 @base=#<Card id: nil, card_colour_id: 1>, @messages={:CardColour=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

I've spent hours looking at this, am completely baffled and am at my wits end as to why I can't seemingly do the most simple things in Rails.

I've looked up questions with similar titles, but they all seem to be more complicated scenarios. I have more going on than this example, but nothing more complicated. eg I actually have 3 foreign keys set up, and they all tell me they can't be blank, even if they are populated with valid values.

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176510/validates-associated-not-checking-existence-of-associations) which suggests my code is correct, and will actually do what I want it to (ie validate that the card_colour_id links to an actual object in the CardColour model).

Comment: What does your `CardColour` model look like? You should really try being a bit more idiomatic with Ruby. Try going with `belongs_to :card_colour` and `validates :card_colour_id, presence: true`

Comment: can you show your associations and migrations as well please?

Comment: I am rather new but something is rather confusing: CardColour seems to be a proper model , as well as a column that needs to be filled in for the record to be valid.

Comment: Close, but use `validates :card_colour, presence: true` instead of "card_colour_id".

Comment: The column should be named `card_colour_id`.

Comment: @Orlando I have been trying to be idiomatic. It's frankly confusing. I've edited my question, I made a slight boo-boo

Answer (score 1):

You are validating `CardColour`, but in your console you create a new `Card` with `card_colour_id`, but not with `CardColour`. That is why you get an error.

You should change `validates :CardColour, presence :true` to `validates :your_model's_column, presence :true`

Comment: This works! Thanks! But it seems it will accept any integer as card_colour_id? I thought belongs_to set up a foreign key relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Please change your model code to

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :card_colour
  validates :card_colour_id, presence:true
```

and your new card line to

```
@a = Card.new(:card_colour_id => 1)
```

or with the new syntax

```
@a = Card.new(card_colour_id: 1)
```

Comment: Model class names are supposed to be CamelCase... so belong_to :CardColour is correct is it not?